# New release crashes, when previous app version is overwritten

Tags: android, cordova, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I'm just releasing a new version of my Android app. The problem happens when the previous version is already installed in the device and you install the new apk (with a session started), the application doesn't clear the splashcreen and gets stucked. The only way to run the app, is clearing all the application data or uninstalling the previous release before installing the new one, what is wrong, because you shouldn't now uninstall any app when updating.

Have anyone had this problem? Anybody knows how to solve it?

I already tuned the package.json and everything works fine, excepts for this trouble.

I'm using **cordova 5.0** and **sencha touch 2.4**.

I create my package by using the command

**$ sencha app build package**

and then

**$ cordova prepare android**

I think it may have something to be with the new sencha cache manager, but I don't have a clue on how to solve this. Can anybody help me, please?
 Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I already find out what was happening, the problem was, that Sencha Tocuh generates a cache manifest, and it was causing troubles when the new apk version tryed to overwrite the previous one.

So, to solve this I find out how to package the sencha app without generating the manifest. It was like this:

- add in this files **.sencha/app/package.properties and .sencha/app/package.defaults.properties** the following lines:

  ```
  enable.deltas=false
  enable.cache.manifest=false
  build.enable.embedded.manifest=true
  ```
- Then, clean up the build folder (everything).
- And run this command:

  ```
  sencha ant package build
  ```

And that will make the trick, no delta or archive folders, no cache manifest.

I hope this help someone else!